# In Visual Studio 2005/2008, why doesn't the ">open xxxxx.cs" shortcut work with forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, there is a handy IDE shortcut for directly jumping to a file, i.e.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (to select the Find combo-box)
Then type in `>open myclass.cs`

This is much quicker than navigating through the Solution explorer to open the specified class.

However, if you try and open the code part of a form (not the designer part) in this way then Visual Studio simply returns:

> The operation could not be completed

... which means that I have to go through the Solution explorer to open them.

Is there any way to get this shortcut to work for forms, or is there some other shortcut?

**Update: the problem seems to be with intellisense...**

If I type `>open form1.cs` then this works...

But if I type `>open form` and then use the up and down keys to select from the intellisense, so that the combo reads `>open "Form1.cs (OpenShortcutTest)"` then that operation will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use <kbd>F7</kbd> to view the code behind? Maybe I'm missing something?

[edit]I just tried it in VS 2008 and ">open form2.cs" works fine.[/edit]

Comment: To use F7 you first have to highlight the file in the Solution Explorer, which is a lot slower than using the ">open" shortcut - for us at least where are solution is very large with multiple projects.

Not sure why ">open" on forms works for you.  Are your forms made of 3 parts? e.g. ...

Comment: form2.cs, form2.Designer.cs and form2.resx? i.e. it was automatically generated by Visual Studio 2005/2008 and uses partial classes?  I think that is something to do with the problem.

Comment: (in the 1st comment I meant that "our" solution is very large... i.e. 50+ projects, and the forms are often nested inside folders... so to navigate through the GUI to a form will involve multiple clicks and scrolls).

Comment: I just did a new windows forms project and added a few forms through Visual Studio and then did the shortcut you mentioned and it worked fine. The reason I mentioned f7 is because I thought you had the form open in design view and wanted to quickly get to the code behind.

Comment: Have accepted your answer as it helped me realise the problem was with the intellisense.